# laravel 5.4 Compact() function is not passing the data

Tags: laravel-5

I am trying to pass data to the view using show method. here is my code to go show method `<a href="{{route('user.show',$users->name)}}">{{$users->name}}</a>`

This is my show method

```
public function show($id)
{
    $name = User::find($id);
    return route('user.show',$name,compact($name));
}
```

This is my view code

```
<div class="title m-b-md">
 Individual page
 {{$name}}
</div>
```

But it is showing me just '\' this symbol in my view as output.Even while I am not give {{$name}} in my view it also show this symbol. can you please help me please

Answer (score 0):

The function route is used to redirect the user on particular URL.
compact function work when you are passing your data into view file.
something like:

```
view()->make('path_to_your_view',compact($name));
```

Now, in this case, you can use two technique to pass data
1) Use session
2) Use view()->share() method.

Something like:

```
session()->flash('name',$name);
```

or

```
view()->share('name',$name);
```

and then you redirect the user to the route.